# Eclipse/Force.com IDE not displaying errors in Problems pane - Summer 14 sandbox

Tags: force.com, eclipse

I have been getting the 'File only saved locally, not to server' error today, and after checking Build Automatically, Work Offline and that the classes were listed in the project metadata listing, I deleted my project and created a new one. No difference.

I did discover, however, that the file(s) will be saved to the server if they compile/have no errors -- it's just that the errors, if there are any, do not appear in the Problems pane with a line number - the Problems tab indicates 0 errors, xNumber of Warnings, etc. and the little yellow warning icon appears at the top of the file and in the Package Explorer.

Any thoughts on this, aside from reinstalling the Force.com IDE itself?

Comment: I noticed this same problem within the last two days.

Comment: What release is the Org you are connecting to on? Is it Summer 14?

Comment: You can check on the errors in Salesforce. Go to Setup > Deploy > Deploy Status (or something like that)

Comment: which version of eclipse are you using? it it new instillation or you used to see error before and now suddenly it stopped? ?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses - Yes, I am connecting to Summer '14, and thank you for the details re: reviewing the errors from within Setup.  Handy, but time consuming :D  Eclipse is not a new installation, but I think I b0rked it by shutting down/quitting eclipse before a test was finished..?  I guess I need to re-install.

Answer (score 13):

There are a couple of issues in Summer '14 that are causing pain with the Metadata API:

- The `checkDeployStatus()` API call does not return deploy messages for API versions 28.0 and below. See [known issue on the Success site](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4XPAA0).
- Deployments via the Metadata API can succeed (as you are seeing - the files are saved) and the `DeployMessage` contains `success: true`, but it also contains `problemType: Error` - this is no doubt confusing Metadata API clients. See [known issue on the Success site](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4g8AAC).

Both of these issues have now been fixed and rolled out to the Summer '14 sandboxes. See the links above for details.

Comment: Any update on a fix for this issue?

Comment: First issue (deploy messages not returned) should be fixed now in Summer '14 orgs. Second issue (bad error response) should be fixed this week - safe harbor.

Comment: I added links to the issues on Success; you'll be able to see the fixes rolled out there. Looks like the first one is partially rolled out.

Comment: Should be all fixed now.

Answer (score 3):

I think this related to summer14 release, not ecliose, because mavens mate ( IDE plugin for sublime) also has been having save/compile problems.

Comment: Yep, Salesforce keeps changing the format of their error responses, which makes it pretty challenging for plugins to parse them properly

Comment: also seeing the issue outside of summer '14 orgs

Comment: Grr, argh.  I installed Juno and the latest version of Force.com IDE, and now deployments are working correctly on the Salesforce side; IDE flags each class I save, in the Package Explorer window for my Summer '14 sandbox, as 'dirty', but in the class pane there's no such indication, and in Setup / Deploy / Deployment I get Deploy: Succeeded.  Tedious, but better than not deploying.  I hope the issue is fixed soon!

Comment: @DuncanStewart just switch to maven's mate, at least then you can actually fix your own bugs, and not wait for r&d to prioritize things

Answer (score 2):

Salesforce R&D have identified the issue.

The root cause of this issue is that metadata API is returning the problem type as "Error" for components which were successfully saved. IDE relies on problem type to report warnings/errors and so incorrectly reports warnings on successfully saved components.

The fix is to not return problem type for successfully saved components (188 behavior). This would make IDE stop showing misleading warning messages.

This fix is being rolled out to the users in a patch release today.
Please verify and let us know.

Comment: this sucks, documentation is non-existent for tooling api responses, and they change randomly with each release, sometimes it's "Error", sometimes it's "ErrorMsg", sometimes its "CompileErrors". If you have any way to escalate this, it would be really helpful to tooling devs out there to have some consistency in the responses or at least just document them ...

Answer (score 1):

I had to abandon Eclipse a couple weeks ago because I couldn't get past that same issue, I had to switch over to MavensMate because I really didn't enjoy using the Dev console.  You should look into using MavensMate it's a really nice tool(atleast until Eclipse is back up).  MavensMate does have it's issues, but it is weathering the Summer `14  migration better than Eclipse.  The only I had an issue was with the API which I found a band aid for here.

[Mavens Mate Metadata container](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40154/mavens-mate-metadata-container/40155#40155)

Comment: patch is available for that now, see https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/290 for discussion, patch https://github.com/joeferraro/mm/pull/25