# OPERATION FAILED - error in Mavensmate sublime. File not saved or compiled on the server. Anyone experienced this error?

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

It was working correctly without complaining last week. But today i just changed a label for the text field in visualforce page and try to save and got this issue. Dont know how to proceed further. I havent saw this type of error before in eclipse or in mavensmate as weel. I am using developer sandbox. Any thoughts?

> MavensMate for Sublime Text v3.5.0
>
> Operation: Compiling:
>   d:\Projects\workspace\DMSand_16June2014\src\pages\OpenDocuments.page
>   Timestamp: Mon, 16 Jun 2014 19:58:16    Result: [OPERATION FAILED]:
>   Resource  Not Found. Response content: [{u'errorCode': u'NOT_FOUND',
>   u'message': u'Provided external ID field does not exist or is not
>   accessible: '}]

Comment: This is a bug that's going around with Summer 14 sandboxes: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40154/mavens-mate-metadata-container

Comment: Thanks @JeremyNottingham. Should i remove this post or keep this one?

Comment: If you feel like the other question includes all relevant information, I would delete this one and make it easier for the next person to find the solution by searching.

Comment: The comments in that thread contains different opinions but none of them insists a concrete solution. I would let this post for a while and would wait for some more inputs. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with Mavens Mate as posted [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40154/mavens-mate-metadata-container), with a temporary solution. There is currently an open issue for this in the MavensMate Github : Error saving files to sandbox with Summer'14. https://github.com/joeferraro/MavensMate/issues/290

Fixed by By setting  `setting mm_compile_with_tooling_api = false;` should allow you to get some work done.