# Summer 14 - Eclipse IDE V29 - Incompatible?

Tags: apex, eclipse, summer14

My sandbox upgraded to Summer 14 and I needed to do some development. Odd stuff happens now; never happened on V30 (Spring 14)

Open Eclipse IDE (I'm using V29), create new Class `FooBar`...wait for class to be created.
Result is three warning messages (file not saved) with class tagged by yellow warning symbol in Package Explorer pane

[image: Eclipse IDE warnings]

Yet the new class is saved on the server within the sandbox!
[image]

The problem gets successively worse, compile errors don't surface onto Eclipse in all cases.  Development is impossible within Eclipse V29 - Summer 14.

What did I try?

1. Deleted Eclipse Project and rebuilt new project from Summer 14 sandbox - no effect
2. Looked at [Eclipse/Force.com IDE not displaying errors in Problems pane - Summer 14 sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40152/eclipse-force-com-ide-not-displaying-errors-in-problems-pane) -- I'm getting similar results
3. Looked at Force.com IDE log to see what IDE is troubled by:

   ```
   WARN [2014-06-12 17:28:01,675] (ComponentFactory.java:getCompositeComponentFromComponent:1093) - Unable to load existing 'classes/FooBar.cls-meta.xml' from project - associated component's file resource is null.  Assuming new.

   WARN [2014-06-12 17:28:02,493] (ComponentFactory.java:getComponentBean:1145) - Unable to get component for id 'FlexiPage': Unable to get bean for id 'FlexiPage'

   WARN [2014-06-12 17:28:19,714] (Utils.java:loadDocument:823) - Unable to load document: C:\Users\me\eclipseWs\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.projects\myProj v31\com.salesforce.ide.core\packageCache.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)

   WARN [2014-06-12 17:28:19,716] (ComponentController.java:run:370) - Unable to update cache with new component Apex Class - cache is not found
   ```

I'm not sure any of the above is relevant.  As I said earlier, none of this was happening when my Eclipse was associated to my V30 sandbox (Spring 14)

I'd surmise that V31 is sending some non-backward compatible messages to Eclipse IDE on class save operations and the IDE gets confused.

What to do?

Option 1: Looking at [Eclipse/Force.com IDE not displaying errors in Problems pane - Summer 14 sandbox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40152/eclipse-force-com-ide-not-displaying-errors-in-problems-pane), I see one user resolved by reinstalling Eclipse and IDE so that is next up for me unless someone has found an easier amelioration.

Option 2: Switching to Mavensmate is another possibility but Eclipse is our standard here.

Option 3: Using Developer Console for development is a last resort but this would be a big step backwards.

Option 4: Wait for SFDC to fix this

> Option 5: (1) Build a new sandbox from PROD which will be on Spring 14, (2) build a new Eclipse project from that sandbox, and (3) deploy all work in process from the Summer 14 sandbox to the newly-created Spring 14 sandbox.  Reliable.
>
> Update 2014-06-16 - I see in [related post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/40718/2602) that a fix is on its way.
>
> Update 2014-06-19 1600h Pacific - still 'broken'; I'm using option 5 now

Comment: Beware that there are issues with MavensMate and Summer 14 when using the tooling api. Ref: [Mavens Mate Metadata container](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/40154/mavens-mate-metadata-container)

Comment: Lovely -- there goes one option <sigh>. I should shoot myself for letting my main dev sandbox get upgraded to Summer 14.  This is a recurring theme w/ SFDC, development breaks in some fashion when SFDC version changes.

Comment: You can still use mavensmate, though change the settings to use the metadata API

Comment: I've noticed this, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Salesforce R&D have identified the issue.

The root cause of this issue is that metadata API is returning the problem type as "Error" for components which were successfully saved. IDE relies on problem type to report warnings/errors and so incorrectly reports warnings on successfully saved components.

The fix is to not return problem type for successfully saved components (Spring release behavior). This would make IDE stop showing misleading warning messages.

This fix is being rolled out to the users in a patch release the coming tuesday( 24th june).

Comment: Is there source citing this or not?